# How to Limit Number of Items in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

How can I limit the number of items **displayed** by the RecyclerView ?

I can limit the amount inserted it if I override `getChildCount`, but that causes it to only insert that number and then stop. I want it to keep inserting/scrolling, but only *display* X number of items.

(Note: The height of each item can differ, so it's important that the limit is based on quantity rather than some hard coded value.)

Answer (score 28):

Inside your Recyclerview's adapter class;

```
private final int limit = 10;


 @Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if(ad_list.size() > limit){
        return limit;
    }
    else
    {
        return ad_list.size();
    }

}
```

Comment: this is the same answer that @mohamed aouled issa mentioned

Comment: Nice Answer @jhashane Can you help if item is show by limit then how can we show more list if user click button..????

Comment: I think this improves your code readability: `return Math.min(ad_list.size(), limit)`

Comment: @jhashane , this answer only returns the first few till it hits the limit. we want all the items while being able to scroll through them.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to set width of each child programmatically,

```
@Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.MY_ITEM_TO_INFALTE, parent, false);

        itemView.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (getScreenWidth() / NUMBERS_OF_ITEM_TO_DISPLAY); /// THIS LINE WILL DIVIDE OUR VIEW INTO NUMBERS OF PARTS

        return new MyCreationItemAdapter.MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    public int getScreenWidth() {

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);

        return size.x;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

In your Adapter, just set a limit,

```
   @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            int limit = 5;
            return Math.min(diseasesList.size(), limit);
    
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply override `getCount()` method and test if adapter data array is superior than "DESIRED_MAX" then return "DESIRED_MAX" else just return the data array length or size (array/ArrayList)

Comment: nah, that's no good because it stops adding new items after DESIRED_MAX is hit

Answer (score 1):

if you want it to keep inserting/scrolling, but only display X number of items, then I have a solution: `setVisibility` to VISIBLE for X items, and other is GONE.

```
public static final class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        handleShowView(view);
    }

    private void handleShowView(View view) {
        if (getAdapterPosition() > X - 1) {
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return;
        }
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is find the dp it takes for one of your list items in the recycler view.
Ex: 150dp ea/item.

then in the XML:

```
<RecyclerView
....
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:layout_constraintHeight_max="300dp" 
/>
```

This means if you have < 300dp / approximately 2 items inside the recycler view, it will wrap content, but if it exceeds 300dp / more than 2 items, it will recycle the whole view while displaying 2 at a time.

Answer (score 0):

***warning with latest libs from 01/2023 (androix, recyclerview, etc)
This "might" have worked, but maybe not anymore...

I am still investigating, but this seems to lead to exceptions:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return Math.min(mDiffer.getCurrentList().size(),mListLimit);
}
```

The second I load more items into the list then "mListLimit" allows, it crashes my app. I have to load itemcount>mlistlimit at once and the line above will throw mentioned exception. if I just use :

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDiffer.getCurrentList().size();
}
```

then I get no exception. Mind you right now it has to very specific values:
listlimit is 300. I load 20 items. Then I load 1000, which will lead to "overflow" the allowed list, only then it will crash.

Maybe this helps someone.