# How to limit grid layout in recycler vertically - Android?

Tags: android

Here is the example of how to limit adding items based on horizontal limit. This logic is based on the width of the screen
[How to Limit Number of Items in RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50867570/how-to-limit-number-of-items-in-recyclerview)

But is there a way to make the same kind of logic for vertical limit?

In perfect scenario to restrict adding new items if new item creates a new line that hovers another view. To prevent hovering another view with the grid line.

In non perfect maybe there is a some way to count number of lines and limit number of lines. Or maybe there is a way to measure the % of the recycler of the screen so if % > 25% vertically so we can't add new item.

Just need any ideas how to play around with that?